# How can I run OpenSSH under AmigaDOS?

Tags: amiga, software, file-system

I want to use OpenSSH for Amiga, copied `ssh` and other files to OS:Utilities from extracted archive, but I'm unable to run the binary. Tried to set protection but it didn't help either. How to make it a command like `adf2disk` or others that came as one file binary?

Source: http://aminet.net/package/comm/tcp/openssh-bin

[image]

Comment: Copied ssh from where?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as stated in the aminet readme

***Architecture:    ppc-amigaos***

The `ssh` executable has a ELF fourcc id, not a standard amiga hunk 03F3 id.

You're trying to run the program on a classic 68k amiga, but you need a powerpc cpu board on OS4 to run it.

It's tough (most links are dead) but possible to find OS3/classic amiga versions.

One is still available here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/amiga/files/OpenSSH/3.9/openssh-3.9p1.lha/download

I have downloaded it and checked the `ssh` file and it has a classic 0x3F3 header means it can run on a 68k amigaos architecture.

Not sure of the usefulness, because if it's not maintained anymore, it could be obsolete for the newer protocols. Trying to do modern things with classic Amigas is more and more a challenge.